# changing user profile path doesn't really work

Tags: 7, users

I'm new in Drupal and have only been touching this for the past two weeks.

I have read several stuff and managed to change the user path from www.example.com/users/[user:name] to www.example.com/[user:name] following [this thread](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12905/is-there-a-module-to-change-the-user-profile-url).

However, when I view other person's profile page, that whole page information is still mine. For example I logged in as Tamia, wanted to view Jack's profile page. 
What I see is the URL really changed to www.example.com/jack-white but username, cover pictures, everything else other than URL and metatags still showing Tamia's.

I'm using Drupal Commons 3 and sadly they don't have documentation for many things.

I tried to view what $vars has in template_preprocess_page and couldn't see much information to change information pointing to Jack instead of Tamia.

Could anyone point where am I missing, please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have provide permission "View user profiles" for the user roles?

Comment: Hi Jayendra, Yes I have. :) Everything was working as per normal before I change the user paths...

Comment: If there are already url alias for any users and you change the setting for pathauto module, then you need to delete all user alias first and then bulk update the url alias to update it for new pattern.

Comment: Hi Jayendra, Thanks for your help. Yes, I have done that, too.
The thing is perhaps I should be loading $account that contains user profile being viewed instead of global $user that contains user currently logged in. Just that... Where should I do that?

Comment: You should check your user-profile.tpl.php in your theme directory. If you do not find it, copy from user module into theme directory and clear the cache. You should user $account variable instead of global $user.

Comment: I actually created most of my pages through admin/structure/pages since it allows dragging and editing content through contextual links, thus I find easier to locate where each element come from. 
Not sure if this is the correct practise, though.

Exactly my question, I tried to print $account in my page.tpl.php, nothing appears.
Current workaround, I actually load $account = $user->load($uid); in each of every blocks i have on the page...

Comment: If you are creating pages through admin/structure/pages, may be you have not passed correct context for users. If possible, please provide screen-shots for the same. I am busy on some urgent stuff, so it would take time to create check this and create screen-shots for the same at my side.

Comment: Context! Hmm.. maybe that's where I'm missing. I'll do some research on that. Will update you with some screenshots if I failed.

Comment: Ok. I will also try to update you asap.